# How would I go about searching for, and then importing values of a known structure from one excel file to another?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file exported from another program with a bunch of data in it. From all of this data, I only need certain pieces of it. The data I need looks like this (with different numbers than 1.111 and 4.444):

```
C1:  1.111  4.444
C2:  1.111  4.444
...
C10: 1.111  1.111
```

The file has upwards of 30 sets of this data, all contained in columns A to C, except I do not know which rows they start at and end at. What I want to do is search the excel file for this data, and paste it into another file side-by-side (where C1's, C2's, etc. numbers line up in the same row.)

A YouTube tutorial gave me the following code that would be used to grab values at a known location in the file:

```
Sub ImportFluidData()
Dim FileNames As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("A1").Select
FileNames = Applcation.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Filter (*Analysis.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Open Files(s)", MultiSelect:=True)

For i = 1 To UBound(FileNames)
    Workbooks.Open FileNames(i)
    Range(------------------------).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Fluid Properties.xlsm").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
    Workbooks.Open FileNames(i)
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate

Next i

End Sub
```

My problem is that instead of a known range, I need to replace `Range(-------------).Select` with a statement that searches for and selects the data descried above. How would I go about searching for and selecting such data? I quite literally just started using VBA today, so please try to avoid any VBA-specific jargo.

Thanks for the help!

Edit: the tutorial was for importing data at a known spot in multiple files, so that's why it's set up for looping through multiple files. I only need to search through one file, which will likely make the code a lot shorter.

Comment: which sets of the given 30 do you exactly search? Do you have any criterions?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you find yourself in a situation in which you have a uniform set of data that can be in a random position of a column (let's do the example with the column B):

[image]

If this is the case, then what you need to do is to find the start and the end point of your range. Which means:

### Find your start point ##:

```
Dim startRow As Long: startRow = Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row
```

### Find your end point

```
Dim endRow As Long: endRow = Range("B" & startRow).End(xlDown).Row
```

### Select your range

```
Range("B" & startRow & ":B" & endRow).Select
```

The above will select the range `B9:B14`, but if there were 10 rather than 15 or 20 elements it would have found them as well.

### Looping through the 30+ sets

@pnuts comment made me realized I had "partially" read the question, I report here his comment:

*I think there may be 30+ instances all in the same two columns - ie maybe as the populated set you show (though possibly 10 rows rather than 6) and then 29+ other such sets, spaced apart by a variable number of blank rows.*

In that case you should first of all define the last row of the sheet, i.e.

```
Dim lastRowOfSheet As Long: lastRowOfSheet = Range("Z1").End(xlDown).Row '<-- I assume in column Z there's nothing, please choose it accordingly
```

Hence, you need to Loop through the various datasets until you don't find the last one. which means:

```
'first static definitions outside the loop
Dim startRow As Long: startRow = Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row
Dim endRow As Long: endRow = Range("B" & startRow).End(xlDown).Row
Do While endRow <> lastRowOfSheet
    '************SELECTING THE DATA SET**************
     Range("B" & startRow & ":B" & endRow).Select
     'do what you need to do after having selected the proper range
     '***********************************************
     'last re-definition before to loop again
     startRow = Range("B" & endRow +1).End(xlDown).Row        
     endRow = Range("B" & startRow).End(xlDown).Row '<-- if this touches the end, it means it was the last dataset so we will go out of the loop
Loop
```